# How to create simple lookup data structure for nodes in a tree, without modifying the input tree?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working on implementing a custom programming language, and the current problem I'm facing is how to resolve the AST lazily. That is, certain variables in the tree won't be resolvable until they become activated/set later on in the program, so the AST inserts "waiting" nodes throughout its tree. Then as we encounter variables, later on, that were used in the "waiting" nodes, we replace the waiting node with the appropriate variable value. Pretty straightforward in a conceptual sort of mindset.

*But when I get to trying to implement this I am stuck on how to not create something extremely memory and performance inefficient. I'm not sure how to quickly look-up/find the waiting nodes that a newly encountered variable matches, and then how to replace the "waiting" node.* I'm especially unsure how to do all this without polluting the input AST. Ideally, I would like to create a mapping between the input AST and the final resolved AST to keep the original objects intact and unpolluted.

Take for example this sort of string, which would be parsed into an AST:

```
example {foo}
  {bar}
    hello {world}
      baz
  asdf {another}
```

You can also visualize it in a more simplified tree:

```
example
  {foo}
  {bar}
    hello
      {world}
      baz
  asdf
    {another}
```

So say we had this in code:

```
example
  {foo}
  {bar}
    hello
      {world}
      baz
  asdf
    {another}

set
  foo
  user
set
  somethingElse
  true
set
  anotherThingInBetween
  123
set
  world
  earth
set
  stillAnother
  cool
set
  another
  random
set
  bar
  BAR
```

*(Notice that `set a, b` forms a little tree too, but imagine it does the work of setting variable values like `a = b`)*

By the time it gets to `world = "earth"` it would look like:

```
example
  user
  {bar}
    hello
      earth
      baz
  asdf
    {another}
```

And by the end, it would look like this:

```
example
  user
  BAR
    hello
      earth
      baz
  asdf
    random
```

Only once we have reached "**full saturation**" can we say the tree node is "done" (and ready to be further processed in the compilation pipeline). While variables are still to-be-interpolated, it is not "done" yet, it is in like an intermediate state.

The parsed "basic AST" might look like this:

```
const ast = [
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'example',
    children: [
      {
        type: 'node',
        name: {
          type: 'waiting',
          value: 'foo'
        },
        children: []
      },
      {
        type: 'node',
        name: {
          type: 'waiting',
          value: 'bar'
        },
        children: [
          {
            type: 'node',
            name: 'hello',
            children: [
              {
                type: 'node',
                name: {
                  type: 'waiting',
                  value: 'world'
                },
                children: []
              },
              {
                type: 'node',
                name: 'baz',
                children: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'node',
        name: 'asdf',
        children: [
          {
            type: 'node',
            name: {
              type: 'waiting',
              value: 'another',
            },
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'foo', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: 'user', children: [] },
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'somethingElse', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: 'true', children: [] },
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'anotherThingInBetween', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: '123', children: [] },
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'world', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: 'earth', children: [] },
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'stillAnother', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: 'cool', children: [] },
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'another', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: 'random', children: [] },
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'bar', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: 'BAR', children: [] },
    ]
  }
]
```

The question is, how do you traverse the AST in some way, and progressively mark the nodes as "done"?

It seems you need to do two things:

1. Create a map of the variable name to the node in the tree, for quick lookup without having to scan/traverse the whole tree for each new variable that you encounter.
2. Keep a counter on each node up through the parents, so you know when a node or tree is "done".

Number (2) seems like it can be more optimized than that somehow, but it's hard for me to think deeper about that currently with my understanding of this problem.

Number (1) seems like you need to do something like this:

```
const globalASTWaitingMap = {}

function addToWaitingMap(variable, object) {
  globalASTWaitingMap[variable] = globalASTWaitingMap[variable] ?? []
  globalASTWaitingMap[variable].push(object)
  incrementWaiting(object)
}

function incrementWaiting(node) {
  node.waiting = 1
  // set waiting count on all parents
  // not the most efficient, maybe there is a better way
  // to skip irrelevant nodes.
  while (node.parent) {
    node = node.parent
    node.waiting = node.waiting ?? 0
    node.waiting++
  }
}
```

So then you'd have:

```
function traverseAST(list) {
  list.forEach(node => {
    if (typeof node.name !== 'string') {
      addToWaitingMap(node.name.value, node)
    }

    if (node.set) {
      const variable = node.children[0].name
      const value = node.children[1].name
      globalASTWaitingMap[variable]?.forEach(object => {
        object.name = value
        decrementWaiting(object)
      })
    }

    // make upward lookup fast
    // (ideally would be odne somewhere else in production code)
    node.children.forEach(child => child.parent = node)
    traverseAST(node.children)
  })
}

function decrementWaiting(node) {
  node.waiting--
  // set waiting count on all parents
  // not the most efficient, maybe there is a better way
  // to skip irrelevant nodes.
  while (node.parent) {
    node = node.parent
    node.waiting--
  }
}
```

This seems convoluted to me, and like it won't work. How would you do this sort of thing?

Full code:

```js
const globalASTWaitingMap = {}

const ast = [
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'example',
    children: [
      {
        type: 'node',
        name: {
          type: 'waiting',
          value: 'foo'
        },
        children: []
      },
      {
        type: 'node',
        name: {
          type: 'waiting',
          value: 'bar'
        },
        children: [
          {
            type: 'node',
            name: 'hello',
            children: [
              {
                type: 'node',
                name: {
                  type: 'waiting',
                  value: 'world'
                },
                children: []
              },
              {
                type: 'node',
                name: 'baz',
                children: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'node',
        name: 'asdf',
        children: [
          {
            type: 'node',
            name: {
              type: 'waiting',
              value: 'another',
            },
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'foo', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: 'user', children: [] },
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'somethingElse', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: 'true', children: [] },
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'anotherThingInBetween', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: '123', children: [] },
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'world', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: 'earth', children: [] },
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'stillAnother', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: 'cool', children: [] },
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'another', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: 'random', children: [] },
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'node',
    name: 'set',
    set: true,
    children: [
      { type: 'node', name: 'bar', children: [] },
      { type: 'node', name: 'BAR', children: [] },
    ]
  }
]

traverseAST(ast)

console.log(ast)

function addToWaitingMap(variable, object) {
  globalASTWaitingMap[variable] = globalASTWaitingMap[variable] ?? []
  globalASTWaitingMap[variable].push(object)
  incrementWaiting(object)
}

function incrementWaiting(node) {
  node.waiting = 1
  // set waiting count on all parents
  // not the most efficient, maybe there is a better way
  // to skip irrelevant nodes.
  while (node.parent) {
    node = node.parent
    node.waiting = node.waiting ?? 0
    node.waiting++
  }
}

function traverseAST(list) {
  list.forEach(node => {
    if (typeof node.name !== 'string') {
      addToWaitingMap(node.name.value, node)
    }

    if (node.set) {
      const variable = node.children[0].name
      const value = node.children[1].name
      globalASTWaitingMap[variable]?.forEach(object => {
        object.name = value
        decrementWaiting(object)
      })
    }

    // make upward lookup fast
    // (ideally would be odne somewhere else in production code)
    node.children.forEach(child => child.parent = node)
    traverseAST(node.children)
  })
}

function decrementWaiting(node) {
  node.waiting--
  // set waiting count on all parents
  // not the most efficient, maybe there is a better way
  // to skip irrelevant nodes.
  while (node.parent) {
    node = node.parent
    node.waiting--
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the `name` values guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you *want* to mark nodes as done, since you also write you don't want to pollute nodes. Moreover, your code has no asynchronous actions, so when exactly could nodes be *"further processed in the compilation pipeline"*? As it looks now, the code will resolve the complete AST first, and only then you'd continue to a next processing phase.

Comment: Within the question it's mentioned that after full saturation of the AST tree follows a compilation pipeline.  This implies that the the end state is a compiled language, not interpreted, but it seems that the overall question involves the interpretation of the AST, in particular the resolution of variable references.  That being the case, is this exercise associated with templating in your eventual language?  Also, out of curiosity, what is your target executable (or pre-executable) framework?  (Eg, machine code, assembly, web assembly, C, Javascript, etc?)